# Spring Security SAML DisabledException not thrown

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-saml

I am using spring-security-core v2.0 integrated with spring-security-saml extension V 1.0.1-RELEASE in a Grails application.
After implementing `loadUserBySaml` method (an implementation of `SAMLUserDetailsService`), unfortunately, when user has attribute `enabled` to false, `DisabledException` is not thrown, I have to throw it explicitly in this method, which is not the default mechanism recommended by Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

As per the spring docs spring will not throw user DisabledException if you have attribute named "enabled" .. It will throw only`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException`  Refer : [Spring loadUserBySAML Method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/saml/userdetails/SAMLUserDetailsService.html)

You can have your custom exception and can throw it if needed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however that's what i have already done. I am still confused why i have to throw a custom exception explicitely, spring saml extension at this case doesn't define specific exceptions for these kind of figures. It is the case also for a user account expired exception or user account locked exception.

Comment: As far as i know, spring saml extension provides only limited capabilities... they are checking user/principal object exists as part of saml response or not... if ueser/principal object exists they are setting the same in SpringContext, if not throwing UsernameNotFoundException . In my implementation i have seen spring checking only for user name and authorities .  if you are statisfied dont forget to mark it as answer . The above mentioned link clearly explains what an loadUserBySAML could do.